# How i can display article filter by age in ee2?

Tags: ee2, search

I am displaying age range by using following code.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" search:age="1-20|21-40|41-60|61-80|81-100" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">{age}</a></li>
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

so according to above code i am getting following result

```
<a href="#">41-60</a>
<a href="#">1-20</a>
<a href="#">21-40</a>
```

now i want to get all article of age range ="41-60" as result when i click on range 41-60 how can i get this result ?

i am useing following sturcture for article entry 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question (you might want to try to clarify it a little).

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" search:age="41-60" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
```

If you need to pass the search parameter dynamically then you could use URL segments. So your url might be something like

http://mysite.com/articles/age/41-60

Then your channel entries tags would be

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" search:age="{segment_3}" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
```

You *might* even be able to do something like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" search:{segment_2}="{segment_3}" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
```

You might also want to look at using a search add-on such as Super Search or Low Search as they will allow you to search on ranges rather than fixed strings. (I think EE2.7 may allow you to search ranges also).

Comment: thank you for your help                                    i also know that i have to pass URL like this http://mysite.com/articles/age/41-60 but for that i have to create individual template ? that way i can not use because this way is not right according to me...

Comment: No you do not necessarily need to create a new template but we don't know what templates you have or how you have structured your site.

Comment: hello sir i am using "article" as template_group and "age" as template now you can guide me how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: That's fine. In that case the third segment would normally try to load an entry called 41-60. You have set dynamic="off" and you can use the third segment in your search. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: yes sir i tried your suggestion but not working please check about screen shot of my entry structure.